# Regex match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match the following term in JavaScript using regex.

```
String = 'abc AND def AND igk AND lmn'
```

Terms to match: 
the word before and after first `AND`.

For example in the above string the match part will be : `abc AND def`.

I want to do it in JavaScript. So I will call

```
string.match(/regex to use/)
```

and assign it to a var.

Any suggestions please.

EDIT:

the string can be of form like:

```
    string = 'AND abc';
    string = 'abc AND';
    string = 'abc def AND igk lmn';
    string = 'abc def AND';
    string = 'AND igk lmn';
```

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: So the words before/after are optional? Or should there only be a match if both words are actually present? Could there be a string `'AND'` (and if so, what should happen)?

Comment: Are you interested in matching `abc` if your string is `'abc'` (no AND at all)?

Comment: if i dont have word before or after AND, no issues, i will get blank.
If only AND present my both words will be blank. So words are optional can be present or absent. I will validate them after and have null passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight improvement on Igor's version :

```
   var m = str.match (/(\w+)\s+AND\s+(\w+)/);
   // word before AND in m[1], word after AND in m[2]
```

Automagically extracts the two words.

Comment: i am using it as: /(\w*)\s*AND\s*(\w*)/. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can try this regex:

```
/(\w+\s+AND\s+\w+)/
```

**EDIT** (after having read your last update): if left and right terms are optional, use the following regex instead:

```
/(?: (\w+) \s+)? AND (?: \s+ (\w+))?/x
```

Comment: You need to  remove the `^` or this will fail if there is more than one word before the first `AND`.

Comment: I have made the edit; as long as you don't use the `/g` modifier, this regex will find the first occurrence of `AND` plus the two words around it (provided a "word" is defined as "as series of ASCII alphanumeric characters").

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I put `^` because it was unclear before the OP's last edit what exactly needed to be matched.

Comment: Thanks :0 to match my cases i am using it as:
       /(\w*\s*AND\s*\w*)/